# Can you please advise How to mock the Rest Template

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Is there any possibility to write the mockito condition on it. if not let me know how to change the actual code.

```
 String url = new StringBuilder(EPARTNER_MICRO_SERVICE_URL).append(service).toString();
 RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<String>(prePreocess(ePartnerRestRequestDTO), HttpMethod.POST, new URI(url));

 Instant before = Instant.now();
 ResponseEntity<String> response =  new RestTemplate().exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
 logger.info("ePartner service " + url + " - duration (milliseconds) :: " + Duration.between(before, Instant.now()).toMillis());

 if(isObjectPresent(response) && isObjectPresent(response.getStatusCode()) &&  HttpStatus.OK == response.getStatusCode()) {
        ePartnerRestResponseDTO = postProcess(JWSResponseUtil.verifyJWSSignatureAndExtractPayload(response.getBody()));
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this tutorial? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template

Comment: You should make the `RestTemplate` a bean that is `@Autowired` into your class. That makes it easy to replace with a mock. Also, your `if` statement is unnecessary. The `exchange` call will throw an exception if it receives a non 200 response code.